# Router in bridge mode

Tags: router, bridge

I'm setting up a new router to be an access point in bridge mode.
Here is how my network is layed out:

On side of property:
- Internet
- MikroTik router
- Ubiquiti wireless radio

Other side:
- Ubiquiti wireless radio
- Router as access point + bridge mode
- 3 PCs connected, XBox, Kindle etc.

My question is: if two computers connected to the AP are transferring files, data etc, is the data routed at all to the MikroTik, thus slowing down the network having to go the extra distance?

I know, silly question, but I'm yet to purchase the router to use as the AP yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Ethernet switch portion of the wireless router should be able to direct packets between the PCs without having to access the Mikro Tik.

Comment: If you expect to do a lot of local PC to PC transfers, then spend a bit more and look for a wireless router that has Gigabit ports.  If "Gigabit" is not in the model name (and most do not), then it only has 10/100 Base-T ports

Comment: Gigabit is not required - 10/100 is all I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

MikroTiK has a Wireless N router with gigabit ethernet which would reduce your infrastructure if it allows you to do a wireless bridge to your remote location.